# Traverse directory and store data

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

During one of assignment, I need to directory and store into proper data structure. I did following way and create to store as  tree with multiple child and child will have linked list. Any improvement or suggestion.

```
File format:
    /path1/path2/path3
    /path1/path2/path3/cell_lists
    /path1/path2/path3/path4
    /path1/path2/path3/path4/ALLCELLS
    /path1/path2/path3/path4/ALLCELLS/cells
    /path1/path2/path3/path4/ALLCELLS/cells/fild
    /path1/path2/path3/path4/ALLCELLS/cells/fild2
```

source code

```
    #include<iostream>       
    #include<fstream>
    #include<vector>
    #include<boost/thread/thread.hpp>
    #include<boost/filesystem.hpp>
    #include "subprocess.h"
    #include "Command.h"
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

    void create_dir() {
        fs::path p("/user_path");
        std::ofstream outfile("dir_names_150");
        int maxdepth = 1;
        fs::recursive_directory_iterator end_iter;
        boost::system::error_code dir_error;
        for(fs::recursive_directory_iterator begin(p, dir_error); begin != end_iter; ++begin) {
            try {
                if(fs::is_directory(begin->status())){
                    if(begin.level()== maxdepth)
                        begin.no_push();
                    outfile<<begin->path().string()<<std::endl;
                }
            }catch(fs::filesystem_error &ex) {
                std::cout<<"Boost Filesystem Error"<< ex.what()<<std::endl;
            }
            catch(const std::exception &ex){
                std::cout<<"Standard Exception"<<ex.what()<<std::endl;
            }
        }
        outfile.close();
    }

    std::vector<std::string> read_dir() {
        std::string line;
        std::vector<std::string> dir_names;
        std::ifstream myfile("dir_names_150");
        while(getline(myfile, line)) {
            dir_names.push_back(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
        return dir_names;
    }

    struct Dirinfo {
        uint64_t dir_size;
        std::string owner;
        std::string dir_name;
        std::string dir_path;
        std::string f_time;
        std::vector<Dirinfo*> list;
        Dirinfo *next;
    };

    class Dirmapping {
        private:
            Dirinfo *root;
            std::vector<std::string> dirs;
        public:
            Dirmapping(){}
            Dirmapping(std::vector<std::string> &dir_name);
            void createmap();
            void printmap();
    };

    Dirmapping::Dirmapping(std::vector<std::string> &dirs) {
        this->dirs = dirs;
        root = nullptr;
    }


    void Dirmapping::createmap() {
        for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = this->dirs.begin();  it != dirs.end(); ++it) {
            fs::path insert_path(*it);
            Dirinfo *dirinfo = new Dirinfo;
            dirinfo->dir_path = *it;
            dirinfo->dir_name = insert_path.filename();
            dirinfo->f_time = std::to_string(fs::last_write_time(insert_path));
            dirinfo->next = nullptr;
            dirinfo->owner = "";
            dirinfo->dir_size = 0;
            if (root == nullptr) {
                root = dirinfo;
            }
            else {
                Dirinfo *temp = root;
                fs::path compare_path(*it);
                bool found_root = false;
                while(temp->next != nullptr) {
                    fs::path p(temp->dir_path);
                    while (compare_path.string().length()>2){
                        if(fs::equivalent(compare_path, p)){
                            found_root = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        compare_path = compare_path.parent_path();
                    }
                    if(found_root)
                        break;
                    temp= temp->next;
                }
                if(found_root)
                    temp->list.push_back(dirinfo);
                else
                    temp->next = dirinfo;
            }
        }
    }

    void Dirmapping::printmap() {
        Dirinfo *temp = root;
        while(temp != nullptr){
            std::cout<<"Root::"<<temp->dir_path<<std::endl;
            if(temp->list.size()){
                std::cout<<"children"<<std::endl;
                for(std::vector<Dirinfo*>::iterator it = temp->list.begin(); it != temp->list.end(); ++it){
                    std::cout<<"-->"<<(*it)->dir_path<<std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    int main() {
        create_dir();
        std::vector<std::string> dir_names = read_dir();
        Dirmapping dirmap(dir_names);
        dirmap.createmap();
        dirmap.printmap();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `create_dir()`

This function's name is misleading. It does not create any directories.

```
for(fs::recursive_directory_iterator begin(p, dir_error); begin != end_iter; ++begin) {
```

You are using the `error_code` version of `begin()` to create the directory iterator without risking an exception, but then you don't check to see if there was an error. If your intention is to avoid exceptions outside of the loop, you should probably check the error status, and also use the version of `increment()` that takes an error status:

```
for (fs::recursive_directory_iterator begin{p, dir_error}; !dir_error && begin != end_iter; begin.increment(dir_error))
```

Within the loop body, if you're just going to be ignoring the errors - or at most, printing a message about them - consider using the error code pattern there, too. As in:

```
auto ec = boost::system::error_code{};
auto stat = begin->status(ec);
if (!ec)
{
    if (fs::is_directory(stat))
    {
        if (begin.level() == maxdepth)
            begin.no_push();
        outfile << begin->path().string() << '\n';
    }
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "error: " << ec.message() << '\n';
}
```

This helps avoid expensive exception machinery when all you want to do is print a message and continue.

Avoid `std::endl`. In fact, just never use it.

Catch exceptions by `const` reference (normally) - maybe you just forgot the `const` when catching the filesystem exception.

```
outfile.close();
```

Closing the file stream is unnecessary.

## `read_dir()`

Why do you read all the directory names into a file in `create_dir()`, then open the file again and read all those same names into a vector in this function? If all you want is the vector of directories, you can do that in `create_dir()` (which, again, needs a better name, but then so does this function). If you really want to save the list of directories in a file, it's much easier to read them all into a vector, then write the contents of the vector. That way you only have to open the file one time.

```
std::vector<std::string> read_dir() {
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> dir_names;
    std::ifstream myfile("dir_names_150");
    while(getline(myfile, line)) {
        dir_names.push_back(line);
    }
    myfile.close();
    return dir_names;
}
```

You can write this pattern more idiomatically like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> dir_names;
std::ifstream myfile("dir_names_150");
for (auto line = std::string{}; getline(myfile, line); )
    dir_names.push_back(line);
return dir_names;
```

But that's a matter of taste.

Once again, streams close automatically.

## `Dirinfo`

So this is your linked list node class. I don't really see the point of reimplementing a linked list when you have one in the library: `std::list`.

```
uint64_t dir_size;
```

First, this should be `std::uint64_t`. You should also include `<cstdint>`.

But you should avoid fixed-size types because they're not portable. Instead use `std::uint_least64_t` or `std::uint_fast64_t` depending on whether you're more concerned about speed or space. Or use a more relevant type (which I can't guess what that might be, because it's only set to 0).

```
std::string dir_name;
std::string dir_path;
```

I don't know the purpose of `owner`, but these seem like they should be `fs::path`, not `std::string`. And you don't need both. You just need `fs::path dir_path;`, and the directory name is just `dir_path.filename()`.

```
std::string f_time;
```

It seems misguided to store the last modified time as a string, rather than some kind of time type.

```
std::vector<Dirinfo*> list;
```

Normally storing pointers in a vector like this is a red flag. In fact, you have some serious problems because of it.

However, you're kinda stuck because `DirInfo` is still an incomplete type. You *have* to store pointers (or references).

In fact, what you have is a mess, because it's not clear anywhere in your program who owns what. Who owns all the `Dirinfo` items in `list`? Who owns `next`? Your program leaks every single `Dirinfo` you create, and it's not clear where you'd do the cleanup to fix that.

## `Dirmapping`

You should use default initializers, especially for fundamental types (like pointers):

```
class Dirmapping {
    private:
        Dirinfo *root = nullptr;
```

This will ensure that `root` is `nullptr` even if you forget to make it so (which you do in your default constructor).

```
Dirmapping(){}
```

Prefer to write this like:

```
Dirmapping() = default;
```

Constructors that take a single parameters should be `explicit`, so:

```
Dirmapping(std::vector<std::string> &dir_name);
```

should be marked `explicit`. Also, because you don't modify the vector in the function, you should take it by `const` reference.

```
void printmap();
```

This function should be marked `const`, because it doesn't modify the object.

```
Dirmapping::Dirmapping(std::vector<std::string> &dirs) {
    this->dirs = dirs;
    root = nullptr;
}
```

As mentioned before, this should take the vector by `const&`.

If you use class initializers, you don't need to set `root` to `nullptr` - that will be automatic.

Don't access class members like `this->`. There is no need in most cases.

Prefer to initialize class members like this:

```
Dirmapping::Dirmapping(std::vector<std::string> const& dirs) :
    dirs{dirs}
{}
```

Next is `createmap()`:

```
for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = this->dirs.begin();  it != dirs.end(); ++it) {
```

This is a clunky, old-fashioned way to iterate over a vector.

The first improvement is to use `auto`:

```
for (auto it = dirs.begin();  it != dirs.end(); ++it)
```

Already that's *much* simpler.

But even better would be to use range-`for`:

```
for (auto&& dir : dirs)
```

or in this case:

```
for (auto const& dir : dirs)
```

Even better still would be to use an algorithm that makes it explicit what the loop is doing.

```
Dirinfo *dirinfo = new Dirinfo;
```

Using `new` is almost always a sign that you're doing something wrong. And in fact, you're leaking every one of the `Dirinfo` objects you create. You never do any `delete`s... but you shouldn't anyway. You should be using smart pointers:

```
auto dirinfo = std::make_unique<Dirinfo>{};
```

That means that `root` should be:

```
std::unique_ptr<Dirinfo> root = nullptr;
```

`Dirinfo::next` should probably also be a `unique_ptr`. And `Dirinfo::list` should maybe be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>`. All this depends on who you want to own which objects.

```
dirinfo->dir_path = *it;
dirinfo->dir_name = insert_path.filename();
```

This is only necessary because you made `dir_path` a string. If you made it a path, you wouldn't need `dir_name`, and this would become:

```
dirinfo->dir_path = dir;
```

That also makes `insert_path` superfluous.

```
dirinfo->f_time = std::to_string(fs::last_write_time(insert_path));
```

This is unnecessary if you just store `f_time` as a `std::time_t`.

Let's skip down to the loop.

```
fs::path p(temp->dir_path);
```

This would be unnecessary if `dir_path` were a path and not a string.

```
while (compare_path.string().length()>2){
```

What I suspect you're trying to do here is test to see if your path is just `/`. (I'm just guessing, because your code has no comments to explain your intentions.) This is a roundabout way to do it that won't give you the right answer in all cases. Instead, just use `path`'s members. In this case, assuming your paths are all absolute paths, all you'd need to check is:

```
while (compare_path.has_relative_path())
```

On to `printmap()`.

```
if(temp->list.size())
```

You probably mean:

```
if (!temp->list.empty())
```

And finally:

```
for(std::vector<Dirinfo*>::iterator it = temp->list.begin(); it != temp->list.end(); ++it){
    std::cout<<"-->"<<(*it)->dir_path<<std::endl;
}
```

Once again, this can be written much more simply with a range-`for` loop:

```
for (auto const& item : temp->list)
    std::cout << "-->" << item.dir_path << '\n';
```

And of course, don't use `std::endl`.

The biggest problem to fix with your code is that it leaks every `Dirinfo` object it creates. Use smart pointers, and avoid `new` altogether. Better yet, don't write your own linked list when there's a perfectly good one in the standard library.

I would also **STRONGLY** suggest writing some comments in your code to explain what your intentions are.